# Django URL conf without a view - to link to another domain

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to be able to use the reverse url lookups in order to link to a pre-set domain e.g:

in a template:

`<a href="{% url 'admin_site' %}">Admin</a>`

Where the page may sit at `http://www.mydomain.com/home` and the admin site might be `http://admin.mydomain.com` - or when in dev mode, it might be `http://devadmin.localhost`

I can set the domain in settings using environment variables - but how might I get the URL framework to put that domain in the page template?

Two simple routes to achieve this:

1. Just create a redirect view that might sit at somewhere like `/go/admin` which will just redirect to whatever domain I set up.
2. Include my domain in the template context and rewrite the href something like `<a href="{{ ADMIN_SITE }}">`

Both options would work. But both have drawbacks: first one involves and extra redirect step, second one doesn't use the same `url` tag as other links.

Comment: Must is be without a view? [RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#redirectview)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can/should directly add external urls to your `urls.py`. That file is for URLs that must be resolved from the django server, so if the page is in another server... and, you want to make use of `{% url %}` it must be through a redirect.

I would do this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...

    url(r'^remote_admin/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='http://admin.mydomain.com'),
        name='remote_admin'),
    url(r'^dev_admin/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='http://devadmin.localhost'),
        name='dev_admin'),
)
```

Then `{% url %}` should work as usual:

```
{% url 'remote_admin' %}
```